# If "keyword" in message not working for logstash

Tags: logstash

I am receiving logs from 5 different sources on one single port. In fact it is a collection of files being sent through syslog from a server in realtime. The server stores logs from 4 VPN servers and one DNS server. Now the server admin started sending all 5 types of files on a single port although I asked something different. Anyways, I thought to make this also work now.
Below are the different types of samples-

```
------------------
<13>Sep 30 22:03:28 xx2.20.43.100 370 <134>1 2021-09-30T22:03:28+05:30 canopus.domain1.com1 PulseSecure: - - - id=firewall time="2021-09-30 22:03:28" pri=6 fw=xx2.20.43.100 vpn=ive user=System realm="google_auth" roles="" proto= src=1xx.99.110.19 dst= dstname= type=vpn op= arg="" result= sent= rcvd= agent="" duration= msg="AUT23278: User Limit realm restrictions successfully passed for /google_auth "
------------------
<134>Sep 30 22:41:43 xx2.20.43.101 1 2021-09-30T22:41:43+05:30 canopus.domain1.com2 PulseSecure: - - - id=firewall time="2021-09-30 22:41:43" pri=6 fw=xx2.20.43.101 vpn=ive user=user22 realm="google_auth" roles="Domain_check_role" proto= src=1xx.200.27.62 dst= dstname= type=vpn op= arg="" result= sent= rcvd= agent="" duration= msg="NWC24328: Transport mode switched over to SSL for user with NCIP xx2.20.210.252 "
------------------
<134>Sep 30 22:36:59 vpn-dns-1 named[130237]: 30-Sep-2021 22:36:59.172 queries: info: client @0x7f8e0f5cab50 xx2.30.16.147#63335 (ind.event.freefiremobile.com): query: ind.event.freefiremobile.com IN A + (xx2.31.0.171)
------------------
<13>Sep 30 22:40:31 xx2.20.43.101 394 <134>1 2021-09-30T22:40:31+05:30 canopus.domain1.com2 PulseSecure: - - - id=firewall time="2021-09-30 22:40:31" pri=6 fw=xx2.20.43.101 vpn=ive user=user3 realm="google_auth" roles="Domain_check_role" proto= src=1xx.168.77.166 dst= dstname= type=vpn op= arg="" result= sent= rcvd= agent="" duration= msg="NWC23508: Key Exchange number 1 occurred for user with NCIP xx2.20.214.109 "
```

Below is my config file-

```
        syslog {
                port => 1301
                ecs_compatibility => disabled
                tags => ["vpn"]
        }
}
```

I tried to apply a condition first to get VPN logs (1st sample logline) and pass it to dissect-

```
filter {
        if "vpn" in [tags] {
                #if ([message] =~ /vpn=ive/) {
                if "vpn=ive" in [message] {
                        dissect {
                                mapping => { "message" => "%{reserved} id=firewall %{message1}" }
                                # using id=firewall to get KV pairs in message1 
                        }
                }
        }
        else { drop {}  }
# \/ end of filter brace
}
```

But when I run with this config file, I am getting mixture of all 5 types of logs in kibana. I don't see any dissect failures as well. I remember this worked in some other server for other type of log, but not working here.
Another question is, if I have to process all 5 types of logs in one config file, will below be a good approach?

```
if "VPN-logline" in [message] { use KV plugin and add tag of "vpn" }
else if "DNS-logline" in [message] { use JSON plugin and tag of "dns"}
else if "something-irrelevant" in [message] { drop {} }
```

Or can it be done in `input` section of config?

Comment: I suspect there is an issue with condition inside of your `if`, but I'm having a hard time understanding what are you trying to match with that `vpn-ive` because that substring doesn't exist in the examples of messages you posted.

Comment: Hi @Filip, that was by mistyping. I've edited the if condition now with correct one. But whatever I try, logs are still getting mixed up. The same kind of `if` condition works on other kind of logs and I tried replicating the same here. But no luck.

Comment: The thing that confuses me here is that you're using `tags => ["vpn"]` on the input and saying that all 5 types of logs are coming on the same input, which would basically mean that you're going to add it to every event. In that case there is no point to do `if "vpn" in [tags]`, it's not going to do it because every event is going to match. That being said `else` part of this conditional is set to `drop {}` which means none of the events is going to be dropped.

Comment: If you're referring to `if "vpn=ive" in [message]`, then you need to give me example of what did you find on output that shouldn't be there, because this looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was to assign every logline with the tag pf `vpn`. I was doing so because I had to merge this config to a larger config file that carries many more tags.
Anyways, now thought to keep this config file separate only.

```
input {
    syslog {
        port => 1301
        ecs_compatibility => disabled 
    }
}
filter {
        if "vpn=ive" in [message] {
            dissect {
                mapping => { "message" => "%{reserved} id=firewall %{message1}" }
            }
        }
    else { drop {}  }
}
output {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => "localhost"
            index => "vpn1oct"          
            user => "elastic"
            password => "xxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    stdout { }
}
```